# Use last-of-type only if there is two or more elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am styling a page where I do not know how many elements are going to be on the page. Normally there are two so I have styles to target the first element and the last element. This works well until there is only one element then it get the last elements style.

Is there a way with CSS to ensure if there is only one element that it does not receive the styles for the first or last element. I want to try avoid JS if possible.

**CSS**

```
.content-box
  .item:first-of-type
    // some styles
  .item.last-of-type
    // some styles
```

Comment: Here is a working example for anyone who encounters the same problem, and thanks to @Oriol for all their help  - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYVRqg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class to match the first element only if it isn't the last, or vice versa:

```css
.item:first-of-type:not(:last-of-type) { /* ... */ }
.item:last-of-type:not(:first-of-type) { /* ... */ }
```

```css
li:first-of-type:not(:last-of-type) { 
  background: #ff0;
}
li:last-of-type:not(:first-of-type) {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul>
  <li>First-Last</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can use `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` simultaneously:

```css
.item:first-of-type { /* ... */ }
.item:last-of-type { /* ... */ }
.item:first-of-type:last-of-type { /* Unset styles */ }
```

```css
li:first-of-type { 
  background: #ff0;
}
li:last-of-type {
  background: #0f0;
}
li:first-of-type:last-of-type {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul>
  <li>First-Last</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @misterManSam: Browser support for the vast majority of selectors-3 pseudo-classes is identical. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Hi I've done some tests and the :not selector seems to overwrite the styles that need to stay there in case there are two or more elements. Any other ideas because I need these styles intact? Tx

Comment: Can you include those selectors? An alternative would be using `.item:first-of-type:last-of-type { /* Unset styles */ }` at the end.

Comment: @ClintonGreen The result is expected: since the element is both the first and last `div`, both `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` apply, but not `:first-of-type:not(:last-of-type)` nor `:last-of-type:not(:first-of-type)`.

Comment: I see so how would I go about creating a selector that would omit elements if more than one but target element if only one exists?

Comment: I think you want `.item:first-of-type:last-of-type`, which matches `.item` only if it's both the first and last.

Comment: Thanks mate, that works a treat. Please add it to the answer and I'll accept. Cheers